# MATLAB, ASCII files. Textscan? importdata? load? none of them works

Tags: matlab, ascii

I have to import ASCII files in MATLAB and then have them read. These are the functions I tried out with:

1) `load(filename)` does not work: it says "number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file must be the same as previous lines"

2) `textscan(file, '-ascii')` returns something like "Empty cell array: 1-by-0

3) `importdata(file)` returns " data: [2x1 double], textdata: [4x1 cell], colheaders {'*LOS='}.
It actually works, as suggested  by georgesl, but it treats the full text as a unique column: how can I skip the header and then split the data into 2 columns?

I have noticed everything is all right if I convert the ascii file into a dat one, but I have many files (more than 100) that should be worked out.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: the third option works : your data is in importdata(file).data

Comment: Your usage of `textscan` is wrong. It doesn't accept flags like '-ascii', instead you should've specified the format string.

Comment: You will get better help with this if you add a few lines of your test file to the question.

Comment: you can specify delimiters to `importdata` to make Matlab understand it should make a new column

Answer (score 2):

You can read the entire file into a string using [`fileread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html)

```
text = fileread( filename );
```

Then you can parse it yourself using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)

Answer (score 1):

I like the approach mentioned by Shai, but generally use the command [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)

```
data = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n')
```

so that I end up with a cell array of strings. Makes things easier to process if you are worried about line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
[filename pathname] = uigetfile({'*.txt'}, 'Select File');
fullpathname = strcat (pathname, filename);
    A = importdata(fullpathname,'');
value =getfield(A, 'data');
```

enjoy it!